# Saving Partial Form Progress

Tags: html, css

I am about to start coding an HTML form that is rather long. I would really like to see an option for my clients to "save and complete later" the partial form. I would like them to be able to start the form, decide they need to finish the rest later then save it and come back later, logging in with a username/password to finish the form and finally submit it in whole.

I'm sorry that the above question sounds as if I am wanting someone to build this for me. I have started learning PHP in the last few weeks. I am looking for suggestions and thoughts

Comment: In order to do that you'll need to implement (at least) a JavaScript solution like `localStorage`. The username/password would require some back-end system to store the user credentials and you would need a method for authentication.

Comment: Providing info about what you've tried, how you've been thinking about a possible solution etc. would really help in getting responses here. As your question is formulated now you're basically asking someone to make it for you, which isn't what this site is for.

Comment: What server technology are you using?

Comment: I don't think CSS is of any use for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would some javascript something like http://garlicjs.org/ do?

Comment: This works great except I have my form split between DIV's so  I can achieve a multi-page form. It only saves the first divs information.

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the data persistently for example in a file or in a database, then extract it later when the user returns. The login functionality with username and password is a complex issue involving numerous topics. I don't really know your coding background but judging from your question it seems you should look into learning programming basics and concepts. [PHP](http://www.php.net) is a very popular webprogramming language where this functionality is commonly used.