# Saving and restoring from large html form using PHP

Tags: php, html, forms

Currently I'm working on Large HTML form (up to 100 textboxes/selects/inputs). I want to add feature allowing user to save his progress, to load it in the future. I was thinking about seting cookie and saving form content to the file, but restoring it by inserting in every input value=" is not very clear (and I can't do this for selects!). How can I make easy saving and restoring progress from form?

Comment: Why isn't the current approach (using a cookie) working?  Seems like a reasonable idea to me.  Did you try something and your attempt is failing in some way?

Comment: It is working, but if I want to restore data to every form area, I have  to add to every input/textbox something like that: <?php read_from_file ?> which would be about 100+ repeats, and still I have to generate select boxes in php (to include default to selected option). You see it is not very effective?

Comment: I see that it's repetitive, yes.  But it's certainly effective.  You could potentially save everything in one step by serializing the form with JavaScript and storing the serialized value as a single object.  But when you deserialize it you're still going to have to populate the elements one at a time.  Large forms are large.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14913333/saving-partial-form-progress?       

@David BTW +1 for " Large forms are large"

Comment: IS there no trick, to serialize saving and (more important!) restoring that progress from file?

Answer (score 0):

When user leaves the page, store the form's values in a file with the user's cookie name such that each line from the file corresponds to a field entry type and the value like: `input : myusername`. When user comes back and a file with user's cookiename exists,  `fgets()` the cookie file contents like this:

```
    <?php

        $handle = @fopen("/cokies/yourcookiefilename", "r");

        if ($handle) 
        {
           while (!feof($handle)) 
           {

              $line_data = explode( ":" , fgets($handle) );

              switch( trim( array_shift( $line_data ) ) )
              {
                  case "input":
                    echo "<input type='text' value='" . implode( "" , $line_data ) . "'/>";//user input may contain the : character too, so it is safe to implode()
                    break; 

                   ...
                   ...
                   ...
                   //case for select and textfield will also be modified accordingly. e.g. if( ! empty( implode(...) ) ) echo " <option selected='selected'>implode(...)</option> ";...
              }
           }

           fclose($handle);
        }
    ?>
```